# How to map the GUID with the original file name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I upload the file and add the GUID to the database, and on my index view page, I want to display that file with the original file name in one column and GUID in the next column,  Any suggestion?

class define as

```
public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
```

the index controller

```
     public ViewResult Index()
    {

        return View(uploadedfileRepository.AllIncluding(UploadedFile => UploadedFile.TimeEntrys));
    }
```

and the view

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.ID
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.FileName
        </td>
}
```

So I save the file into my uploadfile database context and try to display that in index view with my origianl file name and guid next to it.

The way I save my file

```
UploadedFileRepository newUploadedFileRepository = new UploadedFileRepository();
    private string _uploadsFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/");

    public Guid SaveUploadedFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileBase)
    {
        var identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
        fileBase.SaveAs(_uploadsFolder + identifier + suffix(fileBase.FileName));
var file = new UploadedFile { FileName = _uploadsFolder + identifier + suffix(fileBase.FileName), ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
        _repository.UploadedFiles.Add(file);
        return identifier;

    }
    static string suffix(string filename)
    {
        string[] names = filename.Split('.');

        return "." + names[1].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model MyWebApplicationNameSpace.Models.MyModel

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>@Model.ID</td>
    <td>@Model.FileName</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of returning a Guid, why not return the UploadedFile Type.

```
public UploadedFile SaveUploadedFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileBase) {

    ...
    return file;
}
```

Comment: that display a list of GUID that associate with the file in both column ,is not what i wanted

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you're doing. The actual model, the controller actions and the view, if you want me to be able to actually help you and not guess.

Comment: That doesn't help, nor does it contain anything I asked for.

Comment: What does `uploadedfileRepository.AllIncluding(UploadedFile => UploadedFile.TimeEntrys)` return

Comment: all the uploadedfile that with GUID(which is not what i wanted)

Comment: Well, you need to return what you want if you expect it to work. A `List` of Items that have the Properties `ID` and `FileName` populated.

Comment: you are right, but I just dont know how to return the original file name

Comment: Show me how you're saving the files then.

Comment: thanks, but is there any other way to modify this without change the data type to UploadedFile, becasue everthing else set up properly except for i want to display the original file name